# Creating a concatenated file in unix then mailing that file to you all in the same script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to create a script which will concatenate all the `out.*` files in the directory `/home/rfranklin/stackDump/` and then pipe that concatenated file to a mailx command - so I can mail it to myself

I've so far tried two methods and neither of them seem to be working. Hoping someone can tell me why!

So far in the `/home/rfranklin/stackDump/` directory I have the files:

```
out.file1
out.file2
out.file3
out.file4
otherfile.txt
otherfile2.txt
```

First of all I tried to write a for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
OUT_FILES_DIRECTORY="/home/rfranklin/stackDump/out.*"

for file in $OUT_FILES_DIRECTORY
do
cat $file > stack_dump_`date +%Y%m%d` | mailx -s stack_dump_`date +%Y%m%d` rfranklin@gmail.com
done
```

This returns:

```
Null message body; hope that's ok
Null message body; hope that's ok
Null message body; hope that's ok
Null message body; hope that's ok
```

And I receive 4 blank emails. BUT the concatenated file is created so I know something is working.

Next I tried to use a here document:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
bash <<'EOF'
cd /home/rfranklin/stackDump 
cat out.* > stack_dump_`date +%Y%m%d` | mailx -s stack_dump_`date +%Y%m%d` rfranklin@gmail.com
done
EOF
```

This does not work for me either. Where am I going wrong!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tee` for this:

```
#!/bin/bash    

d=$(date +%Y%m%d)
for file in /home/rfranklin/stackDump/out.*
do
    cat "$file" | tee -a "stack_dump_$d" | mailx -s "stack_dump_$d" rfranklin@gmail.com
done
```

`tee` copies standard input to a file, as well as to standard output. The `-a` option appends to the file rather than overwriting it.

In your original version of the script, the `>` was redirecting the output of `cat` to the file, which meant that the pipe to `mailx` was empty.

I am assuming that your script doesn't run over more than one day, so I have moved the calls to `date` outside the loop.

Comment: Hi, this seems to work! Only problem is that it sends me the files separately in separate emails, not as one concatenated file..

Comment: That's because you're running `mailx` inside the loop. I assumed that was what you wanted to do from the first example in your question. If your intention is to only send one email, then you should take a look at [1_CR's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27744486/2088135).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point of creating a file here, you could just as easily pipe the output of `cat` to `mailx`

```
cat /home/rfranklin/stackDump/out.* |
 mailx -s "stack_dump_$(date +%Y%m%d)" rfranklin@gmail.com
```

If you prefer an attachment to content in the mail body

```
cat /home/rfranklin/stackDump/out.* |
uuencode "stack_dump_$(date +%Y%m%d)" |
mailx -s "stack_dump_$(date +%Y%m%d)" rfranklin@gmail.com
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Is there a way to use the file names to separate sections in the concatenated file.. for example the above command will send me an email of the concatenation of files out.file1, out.file2, out.file3 and out.file4 and it will look like this:
HELLO
WORLD
HOW ARE YOU
TODAY

and I'd like the email to look like this:
out.file1
HELLO

out.file2
WORLD

out.file3
HOW ARE YOU

out.file4
TODAY

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to concatenate all files in a given directory into one file, and then mail that to yourself. Correct me if I'm wrong.

So first concatenate all files into one:

```
 cat /home/rfranklin/stackDump/out.* > concatFile
```

Then mail it to yourself:

```
dat=$(date +%Y%m%d)
mail -s "stack_dump_$dat" rfranklin@gmail.com < concatFile
```

**Edit**

You can put it in a script:

```
dir=$1
cat $dir/out.* > concatFile
dat=$(date +%Y%m%d)
mail -s "stack_dump_$dat" rfranklin@gmail.com < concatFile
```

run it as so:

```
./script /home/rfranklin/stackDump
```

The `concatFile` will be created in your current directory.

Comment: Could I do this all in the same script though?

Comment: You should be able to